# HTML5 Table 1 cell over two cells

Tags: html, iframe, html-table

I am making a table in HTML5 and I want to have one cell over the other two. I have iframes inside the table. I also want it to have no spacing in between any of the cells (no borders or anything) Thank you.

My code so far:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th> 
            <iframe frameborder="100" src="./top.htm" width="900" height="108" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
        </th>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <iframe src="./left.htm" name="link1" width="160" height="700" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"> </iframe>
        </td>
        <td>
            <iframe src="./home.htm" name="link2" width="740" height="700" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
        </td>
</table>
```

Comment: You have two `td`s not inside `tr`, I don't think this is even valid in HTML<5. Also, what do you mean by "one cell over the other two"?

Comment: As if the top row had all the cells merged together. As of now with my code it places the left iframe under the top and then it puts the home iframe to the right of the top and under it

Comment: I was going to comment when people have answered...Check answers below, it's simply a `colspan` attribute. More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only guessing that the answer you're looking for is a `colspan` on the top row - it's not clear what your question is actually asking though.

Your table code isn't valid, so you should do that first, but basically what you'll want to do is something like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">TOP ROW CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LEFT CONTENT</td>
        <td>RIGHT CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(`cellpadding` and `cellspacing` set to 0 on the `table` will remove spacing around and between cells)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry that I was not very clear with my question

Answer (score 0):

To make a cell span 2 columns you use the [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) attribute in the `td` or `th`:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"> 
            <iframe frameborder="100" src="./top.htm" width="900" height="108" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <iframe src="./left.htm" name="link1" width="160" height="700" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"> </iframe>
        </td>
        <td>
            <iframe src="./home.htm" name="link2" width="740" height="700" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also make sure all your `td` and `th` tags are inside a `tr` row tag.